# windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-2.0

My application uses windows authentication mode.
I have a scenario where i need to move the excel file from one server to another server.Is it possibel to move the files did i get any security problems b'coz i am using the windows authentication mode. Please help?

Comment: Why would you get any security problems?

Comment: What is the exception message you are getting?

Comment: Access Denied is the exception i am getting